# Parse Unsubscribe from Channel iOS Not Working

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to unsubscribe a parse app from a notification channel but my app is crashing.

Here is my app code that is problematic:

```
- (IBAction)genb:(id)sender {
    NSArray *subscribedChannels = [PFInstallation currentInstallation].channels;
    if (![subscribedChannels containsObject:@"gen"]) {
        PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
        [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"gen" forKey:@"channels"];
        [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
        genl.text = @"Subscribed";
        [gen setTitle:@"Unsubscribe" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
        [currentInstallation removeObject:@"gen" forKey:@"channels"];
        [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
        genl.text = @"Not Subscribed";
        [gen setTitle:@"Subscribe" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Here is what my log says:

```
2014-04-26 21:51:28.388 Sulphur Public Schools[5338:3b03] Error: Error Domain=com.parse.networking.error Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 401" UserInfo=0x113ca50d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 401, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/create} (Code: 100, Version: 1.2.15)
2014-04-26 21:51:29.268 Sulphur Public Schools[5338:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Operation is invalid after previous operation.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103445495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001031a499e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   Sulphur Public Schools              0x00000001000772b9 -[PFRemoveOperation applyToValue:forKey:ofObject:] + 0
    3   Sulphur Public Schools              0x00000001000537d8 -[PFObject(Private) performOperation:forKey:] + 198
4   Sulphur Public Schools              0x0000000100015eb8 -[NotiOptionsTableViewController genb:] + 520
5   UIKit                               0x0000000101d52f06 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
6   UIKit                               0x0000000101d52eb4 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 17
7   UIKit                               0x0000000101e2f880 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 203
8   UIKit                               0x0000000101e2edc0 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 530
9   UIKit                               0x00000001020766f7 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 5149
10  UIKit                               0x0000000101d89a15 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 928
11  UIKit                               0x0000000101d8a6d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 909
12  UIKit                               0x0000000101d6229a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 211
13  UIKit                               0x0000000101d4faed _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9579
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001033d4d21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001033d45f2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001033f046f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001033efd83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
18  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001045a2f04 GSEventRunModal + 161
19  UIKit                               0x0000000101d51e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
20  Sulphur Public Schools              0x000000010002ba03 main + 115
21  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001039ca5fd start + 1
    22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I think the problem has to do with the removeOjectLine as my app crashes when I try to press the now unsubscribe button. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the folks at Parse, this error: `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Operation is invalid after previous operation.'` is a result of performing two atomic operations without a save in between. `addUniqueObject:forKey:` and `removeObject:forKey`, for example, are both atomic operations.

So it could be something as simple as the fact that you ran an atomic operation in some other method without saving appropriately; but, from personal experience, I've also noticed, that Parse sometimes mysteriously fails to save the result of an atomic operation and as a result, when saving after performing a new atomic operation, the app randomly crashes with this error.

In order to avoid this `'NSInternalInconsistencyException'`, I personally try to avoid using Parse's array operations as much as possible.  Instead of removing an object for example, I store all the current objects in an array, remove the object from that array, then post the entire amended array back to the database. Yes it's inefficient and annoying, but it's the only way I've found to prevent this error.

In looking at the Parse message boards, it seems as if many people get this `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Operation is invalid after previous operation.'` when altering the `PFInstallation` as you do in your question... For example: [PFInstallations gets into an invalid state with "Operation is invalid after previous operation"](https://www.parse.com/questions/pfinstallations-gets-into-an-invalid-state-with-operation-is-invalid-after-previous-operation).  Hopefully Parse will fix this issue soon.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up disabling the button after the first push until the view gets reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Although seemingly unrelated to the error message, invalid channel names may influence this error.

So Verify your channel names are valid.

In my case, I was attempting to run an operation on a channel named "U.K.", which was producing this error.

Answer (score 0):

I just add a `PFInstallation.currentInstallation().saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)` before the offending line and all is well... 
I do this because if the execution point gets that far, you assume what happened before has saved correctly and therefore it is not dangerous to resave.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I think that is because you are adding and deleting channels at the same time. I fixed it using saveEventually callback block, look at this code:

```
[currentInstallation
 removeObjectsInArray:toDelete
 forKey:@"channels"];

[currentInstallation saveEventually:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (succeeded){
        for (NSString *channel in toAdd) {
            if (![[currentInstallation channels]  containsObject:channel]){
                [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:channel forKey:@"channels"];
                [currentInstallation saveEventually];
            }
        }
    }
}];
```